# JQuery doesn't work after the db loading by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

guys.

I'm trying develope a webpage which has draggable function.
I found a jQuery theme exactly I wanted, and I'm using that code.

I didnt modify a lot, but just added code that loads database using ajax and mysql.
After loading db, the draggable function doesnt work.
I think it's about the order of running the function.
so I used setTimeout on the function that has draggable function and it worked.

But the problem is that I have to load database every 5 seconds, so I cant keep using setTimeout for the draggable function everytime I load db.

Is there any solutions that I can fix this problem?

Here is the code that I use

> **main.php**

```
$(document).ready(function database(){

  if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else{
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
      document.getElementById("gallery").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET","db.php",true);
  xmlhttp.send();

   init();
});
setTimeout(function (){

  var $gallery = $("#gallery");
  var $gallery2 = $("#gallery2");
  var $trash = $("#trash");
  var $trash2 = $("#trash2");
  $("li",$gallery).draggable({
    cancel: "a.ui-icon",revert:"invalid",containment:"document",helper:"clone",cursor:"move"
  });
  $("li",$gallery2).draggable({
    cancel: "a.ui-icon",revert:"invalid",containment:"document",helper:"clone",cursor:"move"
  });
  $trash.droppable({
    accept: "#gallery > li",
    classes: {
      "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-highlight"
    },
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
      deleteImage( ui.draggable );
    }
  });
  $trash2.droppable({
    accept: "#gallery2 > li",
    classes: {
      "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-highlight"
    },
    drop: function(event, ui){
      deleteImage2(ui.draggable);
    }
  });
  $gallery.droppable({
    accept: "#trash li",
    classes: {
      "ui-droppable-active":"custom-state-active"
    },
    drop: function(event, ui){
      recycleImage(ui.draggable);
    }
  });
  $gallery2.droppable({
    accept: "#trash2 li",
    classes: {
      "ui-droppable-active":"custom-state-active"
    },
    drop: function(event, ui){
      recycleImage2(ui.draggable);
    }
  });
  var recycle_icon = "<a href='link/to/recycle/script/when/we/have/js/off' title='Recycle this image' class='ui-icon ui-icon-refresh'>Recycle image</a>";
  function deleteImage( $item ) {
    $item.fadeOut(function() {
      var $list = $( "ul", $trash ).length ?
      $( "ul", $trash ) :
      $( "<ul class='gallery ui-helper-reset'/>" ).appendTo( $trash );
      $item.find( "a.ui-icon-trash" ).remove();
      $item.append( recycle_icon ).appendTo( $list ).fadeIn(function() {
        $item
        .animate({ width: "100px" })
        .find( "img" )
        .animate({ height: "150px" });
      });
    });
  }
  function deleteImage2( $item ) {
    $item.fadeOut(function() {
      var $list = $( "ul", $trash2 ).length ?
      $( "ul", $trash2 ) :
      $( "<ul class='gallery ui-helper-reset'/>" ).appendTo( $trash2 );
      $item.find( "a.ui-icon-trash" ).remove();
      $item.append( recycle_icon ).appendTo( $list ).fadeIn(function() {
        $item
        .animate({ width: "100px" })
        .find( "img" )
        .animate({ height: "150px" });
      });
    });
  }
  var trash_icon = "<a href='link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off' title='Delete this image' class='ui-icon ui-icon-trash'>Delete image</a>";
  function recycleImage( $item ) {
    $item.fadeOut(function() {
      $item
      .find( "a.ui-icon-refresh" )
      .remove()
      .end()
      .css( "width", "96px")
      .append( trash_icon )
      .find( "img" )
      .css( "height", "72px" )
      .end()
      .appendTo( $gallery )
      .fadeIn();
    });
  }
  function recycleImage2( $item ) {
    $item.fadeOut(function() {
      $item
      .find( "a.ui-icon-refresh" )
      .remove()
      .end()
      .css( "width", "96px")
      .append( trash_icon )
      .find( "img" )
      .css( "height", "72px" )
      .end()
      .appendTo( $gallery2 )
      .fadeIn();
    });
  }
  function viewLargerImage( $link ) {
    var src = $link.attr( "href" ),
    title = $link.siblings( "img" ).attr( "alt" ),
    $modal = $( "img[src$='" + src + "']" );
    if ( $modal.length ) {
      $modal.dialog( "open" );
    } else {
      var img = $( "<img alt='" + title + "' width='384' height='288' style='display: none; padding: 8px;' />" )
      .attr( "src", src ).appendTo( "body" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        img.dialog({
          title: title,
          width: 400,
          modal: true
        });
      }, 1 );
    }
  }
  $( "ul.gallery > li" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
    var $item = $( this );
    var $target = $( event.target );
    if ( $target.is( "a.ui-icon-trash" ) ) {
      deleteImage( $item );
    } else if ( $target.is( "a.ui-icon-zoomin" ) ) {
      viewLargerImage( $target );
    } else if ( $target.is( "a.ui-icon-refresh" ) ) {
      recycleImage( $item );
    }
    return false;
  });
  $( "ul.gallery2 > li" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
    var $item = $( this );
    var $target = $( event.target );
    if ( $target.is( "a.ui-icon-trash" ) ) {
      deleteImage2( $item );
    } else if ( $target.is( "a.ui-icon-zoomin" ) ) {
      viewLargerImage( $target );
    } else if ( $target.is( "a.ui-icon-refresh" ) ) {
      recycleImage2( $item );
    }
    return false;
  });
}, 1000);
```

> **db.php**

```
    <?php
$host = "localhost";    // 자신의 mysql
$DB_name = "master";    // 데이터베이스 이름
$user = "root";         // 기본 사용자.
$password = "0000";     // apm 기본 암호

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $DB_name);

if(!$conn){
    echo "fail!\n";
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

//else
$sql = "select * from sensorlist";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$rowcnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$filed_name = array('S_Ultrasonic','S_IR','S_Humidity','S_Temperature','S_Heatindex','S_Light','S_Gas');    //센서 필드명 집합

if($rowcnt == 1){   //right (data가 1행만 들어있는 게 맞는 지 체크)
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        for($i=0;$i<count($filed_name);$i++){
            if($row[$filed_name[$i]] != NULL){
                echo "<li class='ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle'>";
                echo "<h5 class='ui-widget-header'>" . $filed_name[$i] . "</h5>";
                echo "<a href='images/high_tatras.jpg' title='View larger image' class='ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin'> View larger</a>";
                echo "<a href='link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off' title='Delete this image' class='ui-icon ui-icon-trash'>Delete image</a></li>";
            }
        }
    }
    //echo "No sensor";
} else if($rowcnt == 0) {   //data가 하나도 없으면 없다고 출력
    //없다고 출력
    echo "No sensor";
} else {    //이도 저도 아니면 땡!
    //db 에러 출력
    echo "No sensor";
}
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried calling the function passed to `setTimeout` within `onreadystatechange` handler, instead of using `setTimeout`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661019/jquery-ui-draggable-doesnt-work-with-ajax

And

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805210/jquery-drag-and-drop-using-live-events

And

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25551103/jquery-drag-and-drop-on-ajax-loaded-div

Comment: setInterval function

Comment: @guest271314 no, but I just moved the drag event part into there, and it worked!! thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate you event if you have dynamically added elements, reinitialize your draggable plugin after the ajax is complete (do all your logic in the if of the onreadystatechange event)

Comment: Yea, I'm actually doing it using setTimeout, but I kinda wanna know other solution.... (if there is).

Comment: I have to refresh the db every 5 seconds, so....... I dont want to make delay every 5 seconds using setTimeout